# block special characters with ereg

Tags: php, ereg

```
elseif (!ereg("^.+@.+\\..+$", $email)) { 
    $msg="• Invalid email: that is not a valid e-mail address."; $email=""; 
}
```

thats the part of the code im trying to edit it so they cant use `'` and `=` in there email

Comment: ereg? Where have you been all these years?

Comment: ereg() function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged, use preg_match() instead.

Comment: And your decision on what constitutes valid and invalid characters in email addresses might also be wrong. Investigate `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` instead, a proven regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
$email = 'st=ack@overflow.com';

if ( ! filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || preg_match('#[\'=]#', $email)) 
{
  echo 'not "valid"';
}
```